# What does the thing B said mean?

Tags: translation

A: Bちゃん彼氏できたの！？笑
B: イアイアはははは

What does the イアイアはははは mean? Google translate is not helping at all

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an exaggerated "いやいやはははは" (i.e. "nonono, ha-ha-ha").